# python selenium execute_script(): "missing ) after argument list" despite all parantheses being closed?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have many variations but cannot get it to accept my JS.

Tried this (based on a stackoverflow post):

```
driver.execute_script(r'setInterval(()=>{document.body.appendChild(document.createElement "iframe").contentWindow.localStorage.token="arguments[0]"},50);setTimeout(()=>{location.reload();}, 0);)',token)
```

And this:

```
driver.execute_script(
        r'setInterval(()=>{document.body.appendChild(document.createElement "iframe").contentWindow.localStorage.token="' +
        token +
        r'"}, 50);setTimeout(()=>{location.reload();}, 0);'
    )
```

And a few other things but it always gives the same error.

> Exception has occurred: JavascriptException Message: SyntaxError:
> missing ) after argument list

Even after adding a bunch of extra parentheses to the end.

Edit:

here is the original script (not mine) that does work when used in firefox dev-console. My simplified function less version does not work (worth a shot).

```
function login(token) {
setInterval(() => {
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${token}"`
}, 50);
setTimeout(() => {
location.reload();
}, 0);
}
login("token")
```

Using exactly this (made into a one liner) does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Missing parenthesis in the string for "iframe" and an unexpected parenthesis at the end:

```
driver.execute_script(r'setInterval(() => { document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("iframe")).contentWindow.localStorage.token = "arguments[0]" }, 50); setTimeout(() => { location.reload(); }, 0);',token)
```

Comment: No that makes it just not work. The original should have been accurate as it works when pasted into chrome dev-console.